# How do I URL-encode (to pass in URL) the byte string from AES.encrypt?

Tags: python, aes

How do I url encode a byte string and then decode the encoded byte string from AES?

This is my code:

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

key     = "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff".encode("utf8")
iv      = b'\x0cK\x1c\x82\xf1\xa9w\xfe\xa9\x9a\xd0\xb3\x8c\xec1\x1c' # os.urandom(16)
aes     = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
data    = pad(b'HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH', 16) # <- 16 bytes
encd    = aes.encrypt(data) # this works, but it's a byte string, not a string

aes     = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
decd    = unpad(aes.decrypt(encd), 16) # this works, it's a string

a = urllib.parse.quote(encd) # this works
b = urllib.parse.unquote(a)  # this works
can_not_decrypt = unpad(aes.decrypt( b, 16)) # But this one does not work???
```

This is what i tried to solve my question, it doesn't work:

```
a = urllib.parse.quote(encd) # this works
b = urllib.parse.unquote(a)  # this works
can_not_decrypt = unpad(aes.decrypt( b, 16)) # But this one does not work???
```

Comment: A help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest to use `base64.b64encode` to encode it to base64. The base64 string will contain /,+ and = characters, so you should quote the base64 string or tell b64encode to use other characters.

Comment: @treuss, i tried it, but i got "output must be a bytearray or a writeable memoryview" when i tried this part: unpad(aes.decrypt( the_result_of_b64decode, 16))

Comment: LOL, you are passing 16 as second argument to decrypt as opposed to unpad!

Comment: @treuss, i don't undrstand?

Comment: @treuss, okay i got the error, but it leads to another error?

Answer (score 4):

You are passing 16 as second argument to decrypt, as opposed to unpad.

```
can_not_decrypt = unpad(aes.decrypt( b, 16))
```

should be

```
can_not_decrypt = unpad(aes.decrypt(b), 16)
```

Working example with urllib.parse:

```
import urllib.parse
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

key     = "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff".encode("utf8")
iv      = b'\x0cK\x1c\x82\xf1\xa9w\xfe\xa9\x9a\xd0\xb3\x8c\xec1\x1c' # os.urandom(16)
aesenc  = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
data    = pad(b'AllworkandnoplaymakesJackadullboyAllworkandnoplaymakesJackadullboyAllworkandnoplay...', 16)
encd    = aesenc.encrypt(data) # this works, but it's a byte string, not a string

aesdec = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
a = urllib.parse.quote(encd)
print("Urlencoded: {}".format(a))
b = urllib.parse.unquote_to_bytes(a)
decd = unpad(aesdec.decrypt(b), 16)
print("Decoded: {}".format(decd))
```

Working example with base64 instead of urllib:

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad

key     = "00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff".encode("utf8")
iv      = b'\x0cK\x1c\x82\xf1\xa9w\xfe\xa9\x9a\xd0\xb3\x8c\xec1\x1c' # os.urandom(16)
aesenc  = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
data    = pad(b'AllworkandnoplaymakesJackadullboyAllworkandnoplaymakesJackadullboyAllworkandnoplay...', 16)
encd    = aesenc.encrypt(data) # this works, but it's a byte string, not a string

aesdec = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
a = base64.b64encode(encd, b"-_")
print("Base64: {}".format(a.decode('ascii')))
b = base64.b64decode(a, b"-_")
decd = unpad(aesdec.decrypt(b), 16)
print("Decoded: {}".format(decd))
```

Comment: thank you, but how come i didn't get the original value? I get "b'\x81\xcb\xeb\xe3V\xce\xc4\xc9\x91\x1cj\xd1\xaf\x9d\x10LHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH'" instead of  just "HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH"

Comment: Probably because you are trying to use your aes object multiple times?

Comment: no, i don't think so, friend.

Comment: If you are using the code in the original post, you call aes.decrypt in line 11 and line 15 on the same object.